# document.referrer of iframe parent

Tags: iframe, document, referrer

I have a page - page1.html, which contains iframe with url(src) iframepage.html. When I click on the link from iframepage, I go to some other website - page2.html. If i call document.referrer on the page2.html, I have the iframepage url. This is correct according to document.reffer definition - which is the document, that opened current document, but:

Is there any way to get as document.referrer on page2.html the page1.html?

From page2.html I have to know from which browser url was page2.html opened.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In page2.html you can check `window.parent.location.href` in javascript to return the URL of the parent containing the `<iframe>`.

Comment: Neither `document.referrer` nor `window.parent.location` will work on cross-origin requests.

Comment: @AlejandroGarcíaIglesias You are right that a cross origin iframe would block you from accessing the `window.parent` object. However, you are allowed access to `document.referrer` as this is a property on the same document, _not_ on the parent.

Comment: @OliC indeed you can access `document.referrer` inside a cross-origin iframe, but only if the host page is served through a web server and not a local file.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome, you would be able to use:

```
window.location.ancestorOrigins;
```

This will return the parent window URL for the page outside of the iframes.

However, this is not possible in Firefox or IE unfortunately, the best you can get 
is `document.referrer` in these.